# Layout_weight doesn't work for buttons in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

`android:layout_weight` doesn't work for buttons in toolbar. Buttons have `0dp` width as declared, like there is no `layout_weight` parameter. I don't get it. Thanks.

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/Base.Animation.AppCompat.Dialog">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:progress="?android:attr/scrollbarDefaultDelayBeforeFade" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/dd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `layout_weight` is an attribute of `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. `Toolbar.LayoutParams` doesn't support weights. In plainer terms, weights don't do anything in a `Toolbar`.

Comment: So is there some way to set buttons weight depending on device screen?

Comment: Easiest thing to do is probably to just wrap the `Button`s in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thank you Mike, it works